# How to store an instance of a class that inherits from dictionary in the viewstate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, viewstate, html

In a webpage, I am storing a `Dictionary` in the `ViewState` :

```
Dictionary<string, string> items = new Dictionary<string, string>();
ViewState["items"] = items;
```

It works great. However, for some reasons, I want to use my own class instead of using `Dictionary` directly :

```
class MyDictionary : Dictionary<string, string> 
{
   ... 
}
MyDictionary items = new MyDictionary();
ViewState["items"] = items;
```

It doesn't work as expected. ASP.NET complains about the fact

> *MyDictionary is not marked serializable*

It's ok since class attributes are not herited. So I changed my code :

```
[Serializable]
class MyDictionary : Dictionary<string, string> { ... }
```

But if I do so, I get another error message, this time after page postback :

> *The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.*
>   *System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(Stream inputStream)*

If viewstate can serialize a `Dictionary`, why it doesn't work for a class that inherit from it ? How to make this work?

Comment: Are you adding controls dynamically, or anything like that, on the page? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946374/the-state-information-is-invalid-for-this-page-and-might-be-corrupted-only-in   Your custom dictionary is fine, it should be in the ViewState without issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to a deserialization constructor to your class.

```
class MyDictionary : Dictionary<string, string> 
{
   public MyDictionary (){ }
   protected MyDictionary (SerializationInfo info, 
                           StreamingContext ctx) : base(info, ctx) { }
}
```

If you look inside a dictionary class, it requires this to deserialize.

```
protected Dictionary(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context);
```

*Tried it with a test page and it works fine.*