# jquery.load() view-state error with asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i have 2 simple aspx pages (default.aspx , dynamicpart.aspx) 
what I'm trying achieve is that my default page has two parts
part 1 :
the part with default aspx controls (they work with normal post-backs NO NEED To AJAX ) 
part 2 :
 in this section i need to display real-time data! i simply use the dynamicpart.aspx to create a table with CSS and other stuff , then i use $("#DynamicDiv").load("dynamicpart.aspx") to load the real-time section.
it looks really good at the first look but when i try to use the other controls (a postback happens) i get the "The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted." Error i researched and i found out that I'm messing with the view-state while doing this! is there a way to do this without getting that error?! PLZ is there a way i fix this error without major changes ?
here is the code im using to reload the Real-time page.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    refresh();
    setInterval(function () { refresh(); }, 1000);
});

function refresh(){
    $('#DynamicDiv').load("dynamicpart.aspx");
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue and don't know how to get round it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56349673/1331896